# Как можно открыть DLL файл в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll

В написании скрипта необходимо открыть DLL файл и отредактировать его в Python.
Может быть есть специальные библиотеки, которые позволят открыть DLL файл и редачить его?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/252417

Comment: Там в целом описано как запускать функции из DLL файла в питоне.
Мне нужно открыть его и заменить одно значение.

Comment: [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть - pymem https://pymem.readthedocs.io,
как пример использования могу привести чит на кс) - https://guidedhacking.com/threads/csgo-external-bunnyhop-python-hack.11431/